# Cannot push from Bitbucket (SSL certificate issue)

Tags: ssl, push

I'm trying to push my project into my Bitbucket repository but it doesn't let me do it, it throws the following error message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://arfi@bitbucket.org/arfi/quaba.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

What must I do? I don't understand why is this falling now, before it used to work without any problem. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You need to download the certificate file from the BitBucket website and then use it when the Git client asks you about it.

Comment: in which section must I find the certificate into the Bitbucket website?

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved my issue.
I had to open Sourcetree, go to Tools -> Options -> Git, and activate the option 'Disable SSL certificate validation'.

Now I can push my project and everything into my Bitbucket Repository.